# Arduino printing something that i'm not telling it to print

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have written (poorly, since this is one of my first arduino projects) a program that listens to a tcp port and if it receives certain bytes, it responds.

This works, however i am printing "ALIVE" to the serial monitor when this happens. The problem is that it prints ALIVE and then prints the value of the char variables i am comparing.

```
byte responseBytes[8];

char* alive = "ABCD000000000112";
char* clientAlive = "ABCD000000000113";    
void loop() 
    {
      // if there are incoming bytes available
      // from the server, read them and print them:
      if (client.available()) {
          for (byte n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
            responseBytes[n] = client.read();
          }


          char* response = "";
          array_to_string(responseBytes, 8, response);

          if (strcasecmp(response, alive) == 0){
            Serial.println("ALIVE"); //<-- This prints ALIVE and ABCD000000000112
            client.write(clientAlive); //<-- This was added after the issue occured, it is not the issue.
          }

          for (byte n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
            responseBytes[n] = 0;
          }

      }
    }

    void array_to_string(byte array[], unsigned int len, char buffer[])
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
            byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
            buffer[i*2+0] = nib1  < 0xA ? '0' + nib1  : 'A' + nib1  - 0xA;
            buffer[i*2+1] = nib2  < 0xA ? '0' + nib2  : 'A' + nib2  - 0xA;
        }
        buffer[len*2] = '\0';
    }
```

Removing

`Serial.println("ALIVE");`

stops it printing anything. Not just ALIVE

I am at a loss of what the hell is going on here.

Serial Monitor output incase it's relevant

```
ALIVE
ABCD000000000112ALIVE
ABCD000000000112ALIVE
ABCD000000000112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overflowing your variable `response`. By initializing it to the empty string, you've only allocated a single byte of storage. You pass it to `array_to_string()` and which stores `len*2+1` bytes in this single byte array.

At this point you've written data outside the end of the array, the results of which are unpredictable and undefined.

You need to make sure that `response` is large enough to contain the string you're building in it.

Since you know that the response is 8 bytes, this would work better:

```
#define RESPONSE_LENGTH 8

char response[RESPONSE_LENGTH*2+1];
array_to_string(responseBytes, RESPONSE_LENGTH, response);
```

If you modify the variables `alive` or `clientAlive` elsewhere in your code they may also be vulnerable to overflows.

Comment: This works. But i don't understand why Response is "8*2+1"?

Comment: Look at your `array_to_string` function and see that `i*2+1` there. Maybe that indicates you should redesign this function somehow.

Comment: @Mattigins you're storing a null-terminated string in it; the +1 is for the final \0 byte.